# Why does module index make sense?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

On p.10 of Algebraic Number Theory edited by Cassels and Fröhlich, the concept of module index is introduced. My question is that when $M, N$ are not free, how this concept makes sense?

Thanks for help.

Comment: The same page explains exactly what this means. What doesn't make sense about it?

Comment: For any prime ideal $p$, why is $M_p$ a free $R_p$-module?

Comment: It's stated on p. 9 that $M$ and $N$ are $R$-submodules of a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space $U$ that contain a basis of $U$. Combined with the structure theorem for finitely-generated modules over a PID (recall that a local Dedekind domain is a DVR, hence a PID), it follows that $M_p$ and $N_p$ are free $R_p$-modules of the same rank.

Comment: As far as I know, any finitely generated projective module or torsion free module over a PID is free. So I don't know how your conclusion follows.

Comment: Yes, and $M_p$ and $N_p$ are torsion-free since they embed into $U$.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.